# How to change the textbox value from checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the `checkbox` is `clicked` I want to show 24 to come in the `textbox`.
But its not happening.

Script part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#check').change(function(){
        var checkChange = this.checked ? '24' : '0';
        $('#txt').val(checkChange);
    });
</script>
```

Html Body:

```
<body>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" />
<input id="txt" type="text" value="0" />
</body>
```

Comment: Should be working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/e8un6tcp/. Make sure you have `$` available on the page, and that you don't have any errors in the console.

Comment: Did you load `jQuery`in your `head` tag?

Comment: Have yo made a reference to the jQuery library?

Comment: @ojovirtual :D :D:D :D

Comment: add this script above your script -- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I dont know why its not coming ?

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try below,

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Checkbox1').change(function () {
                var checkChange = this.checked ? '24' : '0';
                $('#Text1').val(checkChange);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<!doctype html>
<body>
    <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
    <input id="Text1" type="text" value="0" />
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/JsUWv/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! #SOReadyToHelp BTW, if you upvote my post you will get a Bronze 'Supporter' badge for your first upvote.